# Select2 with Django not accepting selections

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jquery-select2

I've been working on this problem for a couple days now and I am just stumped. Trying to integrate Select2.js without using the django-select2 app.
My model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
import datetime as dt
from WHST.settings import PROCESS_LEVELS
class CEID(models.Model):
process = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                           choices=PROCESS_LEVELS)
ceid = models.CharField(max_length=6)
representative = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True)
functional_area = models.CharField(max_length=200)
score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
ceid_is_production = models.BooleanField(default=True)
ceid_is_front_end = models.BooleanField(default=True)
ceid_is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
ceid_pdl = models.ManyToManyField('PDL', blank=True)
user_edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.process) + ' ' + str(self.ceid) if self.ceid else ''

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.process) + ' ' + str(self.ceid) if self.ceid else ''

class Meta:
    ordering = ('process', 'ceid', 'process',)

def calculate_ceid_score(self):
    entities = Entity.objects.filter(
        ceid__id=self.id).filter(production=True)
    score = 0

    for entity in entities:
        score += entity.score if entity.score else 0
    self.score = score / len(entities) if len(entities) > 0 else 0
    self.save()
    return
```

My view:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.db.models import Sum, Q
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView, FormView, UpdateView
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from dal import autocomplete

from pages.filter import CeidFilter, PmRunInformationFilter, HomePageFilter
from pages.forms import PDLAddForm, PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm, AreaAutofillSearchForm
from tools.models import CEID, Entity, WaferHandlingType, PmRunInformation, ToolPm
class PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociation(LoginRequiredMixin, View, UserPassesTestMixin):
template_name = 'pages/pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association.html'
login_url = '/login/'

def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.is_superuser

def get(self, request):

    form = PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm()

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.GET.get('dat_type') == 'representatives':

            representatives = get_user_model().objects.filter(
                username__icontains=request.GET.get('term')
            )

            representative_response_content = list(
                representatives.values())

            return JsonResponse(representative_response_content, safe=False)
        elif request.GET.get('dat_type') == 'ceids':

            ceids = CEID.objects.filter(
                ceid__icontains=request.GET.get('term')
            )

            ceid_response_content = list(ceids.values())

            return JsonResponse(ceid_response_content, safe=False)


    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):

    form = PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        print(form)
        pass
        # form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages_home_page'))
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

My forms:

```
from django import forms
from tools.models import PDL, CEID
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
class PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm(forms.ModelForm):

representative = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='WHST Representative')
ceid = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='CEID')

class Meta:
    model = CEID
    fields = ['representative', 'ceid']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # self.fields['representative'].queryset = get_user_model().objects.none()
        # self.fields['ceid'].queryset = CEID.objects.none()
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

        if 'ceid' in self.data:
            ceid = self.data.get('ceid')
            self.fields['ceid'].queryset = CEID.objects.filter(ceid__in=ceid).order_by()
        if 'representative' in self.data:
            rep = self.data.get('representative')
            self.fields['representative'].queryset = get_user_model().objects.filter(username__in=rep)
```

Lastly, my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
{% block title %}User CEID Association{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<form novalidate method="post" action="{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}" >
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" /><a
    href="{% url 'pages_home_page' %}"
    ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button></a
  >
</form>

<script>
    $('#id_representative').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term,
                    term: params.term,
                    _type: params._type,
                    dat_type: 'representatives'
                }
            },
            processResults: function(data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {id: item.id, text: item.username + ' (' + item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name + ')'};
                    })
                };
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3
    });

    $('#id_ceid').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term,
                    term: params.term,
                    _type: params._type,
                    dat_type: 'ceids'
                }
            },
            processResults: function(data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                        console.log(item)
                        return {id: item.id, text: item.process + ' ' + item.ceid};
                    })
                };
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3
    });
    
</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

When I try to make a submission, this is the error I get:
[image: Form Submission Error]

The enums are:

```
PROCESS_LEVELS = [('1270', '1270'), ('1272', '1272'), ('1274', '1274'), ('1222', '1222')]
```

I've tried setting the choices for my forms.MultipleChoiceField, but that doesn't solve the problem. I've tried switching the field to CharField and ChoiceField, but that didn't resolve the problem either. I've also tried removing and adding novalidate to the form, but that doesn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can u share your enums like PROCESS_LEVELS ?

Comment: Updated the code with the enums and the imports -- forgot to put them the first go-round. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to get around the problem:
In my forms I created a custom multiple choice field:

```
class CustomMultipleChoiceField(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
"""This field is a MultipleChoiceField designed to override the validation method of a default MultipleChoiceField

"""

def validate(self, value):
    return value
```

Which bypassed the regular form validation procedures. Then I set that custom field to the field in my form, and took it from a ModelForm to just a regular Form:

```
class PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm(forms.Form):

representative = CustomMultipleChoiceField(label='WHST Representative')
ceid = CustomMultipleChoiceField(label='CEID')

class Meta:
    model = CEID
    fields = ['representative', 'ceid']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm,
              self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # self.fields['representative'].queryset = get_user_model().objects.none()
        # self.fields['ceid'].queryset = CEID.objects.none()
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

        if 'ceid' in self.data:
            ceid = self.data.get('ceid')
            self.fields['ceid'].queryset = CEID.objects.filter(
                ceid__in=ceid).order_by()
        if 'representative' in self.data:
            rep = self.data.get('representative')
            self.fields['representative'].queryset = get_user_model(
            ).objects.filter(username__in=rep)
```

After that, it was a simple matter of writing my post request to filter by the IDs of each input:

```
class PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociation(LoginRequiredMixin, View, UserPassesTestMixin):
template_name = 'pages/pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association.html'
login_url = '/login/'

def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.is_superuser

def get(self, request):

    form = PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm()

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.GET.get('dat_type') == 'representatives':

            representatives = get_user_model().objects.filter(
                username__icontains=request.GET.get('term')
            )

            representative_response_content = list(
                representatives.values())

            return JsonResponse(representative_response_content, safe=False)
        elif request.GET.get('dat_type') == 'ceids':

            ceids = CEID.objects.filter(
                ceid__icontains=request.GET.get('term')
            )

            ceid_response_content = list(ceids.values())

            return JsonResponse(ceid_response_content, safe=False)

        elif request.GET.get('dat_type') == 'user-ceid-association-container':
            
            representative = get_user_model().objects.get(id=request.GET.get('term[]'))
            ceids = list(CEID.objects.filter(representative=representative))
            print(ceids)

            ceid_name_list = []

            for ceid in ceids:
                ceid_name_list.append(ceid.__str__())

            print(ceid_name_list)
            response = {
                'representative': representative.username + ' ( ' + representative.first_name + ' ' + representative.last_name + ' )',
                'ceids': ceid_name_list,
            }
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)



    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):

    form = PagesAdminSetCeidUserAssociationForm(request.POST or None)
    

    if form.is_valid():
        
        for ceid in CEID.objects.filter(id__in=form.cleaned_data['ceid']):
            ceid.representative.set(get_user_model().objects.filter(id__in=form.cleaned_data['representative']))


    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

And my html code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block title %}User
CEID Association{% endblock %} {% block content %}

<h3>Please note, submitting associate will reset assignment of CEIDs</h3>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" /><a
    href="{% url 'pages_home_page' %}"
    ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button></a
  >
</form>
<div
  id="user-ceid-association-container"
  class="container"
  style="display: none"
>
  <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-text" id="User"></h6>
      <ul class="card-text" id="ceids"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#id_representative').select2({
      ajax: {
          url: '{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function(params) {
              return {
                  q: params.term,
                  term: params.term,
                  _type: params._type,
                  dat_type: 'representatives'
              }
          },
          processResults: function(data) {
              return {
                  results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                      return {id: item.id, text: item.username + ' (' + item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name + ')'};
                  })
              };
          }
      },
      minimumInputLength: 3
  });

  $('#id_representative').change(function () {
      let representative_value = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          url: '{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}',
          data: {
              'term': representative_value,
              'dat_type': 'user-ceid-association-container',
          },
          success: function(result) {
              $('#user-ceid-association-container').css('display', 'block');
              $('#User').text(result.representative);
              $('#ceids').empty();
              if (result.ceids.length > 0) {
                  for(let i=0; i < result.ceids.length; i++) {
                  $('#ceids').append('<li class="card-text">' + result.ceids[i] + '</li>');
              }}
              else {
                  $('#ceids').append('<li class="card-text">This user has no CEIDs associated to them</li>');
              }

              return
          },
      });
  });

  $('#id_ceid').select2({
      ajax: {
          url: '{% url 'pages_admin_set_ceid_user_association' %}',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function(params) {
              return {
                  q: params.term,
                  term: params.term,
                  _type: params._type,
                  dat_type: 'ceids'
              }
          },
          processResults: function(data) {
              return {
                  results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                      console.log(item)
                      return {id: item.id, text: item.process + ' ' + item.ceid};
                  })
              };
          }
      },
      minimumInputLength: 3
  });
</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

And that seems to have done it!